# Python Script(tkinter application) working fine while running through IDLE, but throwing error running the same python script through command prompt

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having a python script which while running through IDLE will open up a small tkinter application and have assigned different funtions to each buttons. But while running the same script through command prompt as `python scriptname.py`, it also opens up the application but if I click on a button first time it open another same application (duplicate one) and if I click on the same button second time it throws Runtime Error as 'Attempt to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase'

I am trying to create a bat file or exe file to run my script instead of running through IDLE.

Also tried creating an exe file through pyinstaller, but it launches a new tkinter application whenever the button is clicked

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import datetime
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

def func_1():
    curdatetime=str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f'))
    images_dir = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx'
    images_path = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\' + curdatetime + '.jpg'
    **if os.path.isdir(images_dir):
        ImageGrab.grab_to_file(images_path)
    else:
        os.mkdir(images_dir)
        ImageGrab.grab_to_file(images_path)**

def func_2():
    pass


app = Tk()
app.title("Sample Application")
app.geometry("400x50+100+100")
t = Text(app,height=1,width=10)
button1 = Button(app, text="sample1", width=6, command=func_1)
button2 = Button(app, text="sample2", width=12, command=func_2)
b = Button(app, text="Quit", width=6, command=app.quit)
t.pack(side='left',padx=1,pady=1)
button1.pack(side='left',padx=1,pady=1)
button2.pack(side='left',padx=1,pady=1)
b.pack(side='left',padx=1,pady=1)
app.mainloop()

Error while running through Command Prompt:


C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx>python evidence.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\evidence.py", line 13, in func_1
    ImageGrab.grab_to_file(images_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\__init__.py", line 81, in grab_to_file
    backend=backend, filename=filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\__init__.py", line 46, in _grab
    _grab_simple, imcodec.codec, to_file, backend, bbox, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\procutil.py", line 31, in run_in_childprocess
    p.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 258, in __init__
    cmd = get_command_line() + [rhandle]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 358, in get_command_line
    is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.''')
RuntimeError:
            Attempt to start a new process before the current process
            has finished its bootstrapping phase.

            This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
            forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    freeze_support()
                    ...

            The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
            is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.
```

Comment: What is inside `func_1` and `func_2`? Do they interact with Tk in any way?

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] to be able to help you.  The code you posted does not actually exhibit the problem, so I don't know why you bothered to post it.

Comment: Yes in func_1 : Will get user input from a textbox and create a directory and add a file with the name which we get from the textbox        And in func_2: will disable button 1 and copy the files created through func_1 into a word document. Will post the entire code if required.

Comment: If your code is very long, don't post it. Instead create a [mcve] and post that.

Comment: I have added the code for func_1 where I am getting the error and also highlighted the code block in Bold(**) where I am getting the error. func_2 is working fine.

Comment: Check your path env var. IDLE may run on 3.4 while cmd may use 3.7. This happens way too often, so it's worth a sanity check. It probably isn't your issue, but, again, worth a check.

Comment: You want to be able to open multiple copies of your application? Or is that what you are trying to avoid?

Comment: @WarpDriveEnterprises this is python2

Comment: @Novel, Still, it might be 2.4 v 2.7. This an issue python has always had.

Comment: @warp drive Enterprises : I am having only python 2.7 version in my system and also in my env variables

Comment: @Novel : No while running through IDLE only one copy of appl opens and everytime I click on button1 it takes screenshot and saves correctly but while running through cmd prompt first click on button1 opens appl(duplicate) and second time click throws error in cmd prompt

Comment: @user3396433 Alright, thanks for checking. I'm not sure what's causing your issue, but I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause that. You will need to post a [mcve] for us to help further.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you aren't running an old version of your script in a different folder maybe? Try saving it with a new name from IDLE and running the new name from cmd.

Comment: @Novel: Again re-checked the python versions in IDLE and command prompt - both have version 2.7.15. Also renamed the file and ran the script through command prompt but still I am getting error. I have provided the entire code which I am running currently and also have provided the Runtime Error which I am getting while running through command prompt

Comment: As informed previously Clicking on button1 opens another duplicate appl and clicking on the button1 in that duplicate appl throws the runtime error.

Comment: Try adding `childprocess=False` to `ImageGrab.grab_to_file(...)` like `ImageGrab.grab_to_file(images_path, childprocess=False)`.

Comment: Or putting the main block (statements from `app = Tk()` to end) into `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: @acw1668: Hey great, that works like a charm. But one issue is first-time alone it's opening one more duplicate appl and from second time it's working fine. I have included both of your comments into my code.

Comment: @user3396433 Strange! I don't have the issue using both Python 2.7 and 3.7 in my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: @acw1668: Anyways you resolved my issue thanks!!!